# fclose() causing a crash in windows

Tags: c

For some reason fclose() seems to be causing an error in a program I'm writing. The windows terminal says "process returned 255" when it happens. Below is part of the code:

```
FILE* output = fopen("random.txt","w");
write(c,output);
//fprintf(output,"shit\n");
fclose(output);
```

"write" basically writes things into the output file. Even when the program crashes, the data gets output into the file. After the writing operation I can still write to the output file and the text will be there if I do, but somehow closing the file causes an error. 
Could someone please explain to me what the error code might mean (if anything), and how this error might be solved? Thank you.

EDIT:
"write()" writes to the output file and that's all; the only thing it does with the output file is fprintf-ing. It returns nothing because it's a void function. 
Didn't get to see what fclose() returns because apparently the program crashes before I can check the return value :\

EDIT:
Below is the specifics of "write()". I changed it to "write_insult()" to avoid confusion with the system call.

```
void write_insult(Composite c,FILE* output){
printf("lol\n");
switch (c->type){
    case SENTENCE:{
        writeSentence(c,output);
        break;
    }
    default: break;
}
```

}

```
void writeSentence(Composite c,FILE* output){
FILE* source;
int random = 0;
char* fileName = NULL;
int i = 0;
char* number = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
if (c->subtype < 10){
    number[0] = '0';
    sprintf(number+1,"%d\0",c->subtype);
}else{
    sprintf(number,"%d\0",c->subtype);
}

fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*17);
strcpy(fileName,"res/SEN/  /  .txt");
fileName[8] = number[0];
fileName[9] = number[1];
fileName[11] = '0';
fileName[12] = '0';
FILE* tester = NULL;
while ((tester = fopen(fileName,"r")) != NULL){
    i++;
    fclose(tester);
    if (i < 10){
        fileName[12]++;
    }else{
        fileName[11]++;
        fileName[12] = '0';
        i = 0;
    }
}
random = rand()%i;
if (random < 10){
    number[0] = '0';
    sprintf(number+1,"%d\0",random);
}else{
    sprintf(number,"%d\0",random);
}
fileName[11] = number[0];
fileName[12] = number[1];
fileName[17] = 0;
source = fopen(fileName,"r");
Table t = parseFile(source); //remember to free
i = 0;
char* word = NULL;
while (i < t->num){
    if (isInt(t->content[i])){
        word = chooseWord(atoi(t->content[i]));
    }else{
        word = t->content[i];
    }
    fprintf(output,"%s ",word);
    i++;
}
fclose(source);
destroyTable(t);
```

}

EDIT:
I fixed all the string issues, and the error persists. By the way, if I instead declare the file pointer inside the writeSentence function instead of opening the file beforehand passing it in, and close it before the function stops, somehow it's all fine. The compiler is the one that comes with Pelles C, by the way. It did some wonky things before, so could it be that the fault is not on me?

EDIT:
perhaps I should condense the question by asking instead: under what circumstances might fprintf work perfectly on a file opened for writing, but not fclose, which crashes before it could even generate a return value?

EDIT:
Thanks, folks, for all the kind help and advice; I found out I've got an unwanted fopen operation somewhere in the code. That seems to be it, for the problem is gone.

Comment: What do write and fclose return?

Comment: Please post the definition of `write()`.

Comment: Post an example that we can reproduce ourselves, otherwise there's no way to help you. See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Make sure you `exit(0)` or `return 0` from main.

Comment: @meaning-matters not funny but necessary. It can't be libc's write() (at least if writing really works)

Comment: @Mark I've edited that bit in/

Comment: @hmjd changed the function name to something i'm sure that isn't a system call and the symptom is still there.

Comment: @jxh umm, yeah. it's got "return 0" at the end. And if I take away the fclose() everything is fine.

Comment: This "debug a program for me" question adds little value to the site because nobody is likely to run into exactly the same corruption situation in the future; it is about debugging a specific program. The underlying topic is a duplicate of the numerous existing questions about [memory corruption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938491/memory-corruption).

Comment: @Kaz How is that a duplicate?

Comment: @interjay It's the first hit for "memory corruption" in the search box.

Comment: @Kaz: So you decided to mark as a duplicate of a random question the search found without reading it?

Comment: @Kaz I searched all over the place for things like "fclose crash process return 255" and nothing came up; the memory corruption issue is fixed, and the error persists I've not asked anyone to debug it, in fact I didn't even post the code the first time.

Comment: @user2531913 The fclose function works. You pass in a valid `FILE *` pointer. The stream is closed, and the pointer is then not valid any more. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Kaz nothing except the fclose statement is closing the stream; and after the function exits, the fprintf statement still works fine, meaning that the stream should be open before fclose.

Comment: Shortcut: port the program to Linux, run using `valgrind`.

Comment: `fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*18);`: Dont do that. Just write: `char fileName[18];`. It is easier, it cannot fail and does not leak. You can even initialize it to the desired string and avoid the next `strcpy` and the (wrong) count altogether: `char fileName[] = "res/SEN/  /  .txt";`.

Comment: Please take the time to post your solution and mark it as the answer to you. Don't just edit the post saying you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, didn't know how things work around here. I didn't have more progress investigating what exactly caused the crash or what fclose is returning, but it seems there's an unwanted fopen operation somewhere in the code. For some reason that seems to be the culprit, as the problem is now gone. 
Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

`fclose` itself is most likely fine. The problem is probably that you have undefined behavior elsewhere in your code, which is causing the program to crash later. The crash just happens to occur during the call to `fclose`. One example I can see of undefined behavior is:

```
fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*17);
strcpy(fileName,"res/SEN/  /  .txt");
```

This writes 18 bytes (including null terminator) into the allocated 17 bytes. There is also a similar buffer overflow when writing into `number`. And there could of course be other instances of undefined behavior elsewhere in the code, including in functions you haven't shown. One possible way to try finding the problem is to disable sections of code and see if it still crashes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. C errors work in mysterious ways, cos otherwise the functionality seems fine...

Comment: Hmm yes and no. If you're allocated space in a house and arbitrarily take more than is yours, bad things will happen there too. Incidently, you don't need to pad sprintf calls when the number is < 10. You can simply use `sprintf(buffer, "%02d", number);` - The 02d means it will have a width of 2 chars and will be padded with '0'

Answer (score 1):

```
 fileName = malloc(sizeof(char)*17)
```

is exactly one char to short (forgot the '\0'?). Maybe that's all

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating 2 characters (say 2 bytes)

```
char* number = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
if (c->subtype < 10){
```

You then fill the first with '0'

```
    number[0] = '0';
```

and then try to put two more characters into it. That last null will overflow your allocated storage. At this poing you're on borrowed time and who knows what will happen. If you've corrupted something close uses it may break there.

```
    sprintf(number+1,"%d\0",c->subtype);
}else{
```

here too.

```
    sprintf(number,"%d\0",c->subtype);
}
```

Try allocating at least 3 chars for the null termination and also using a checked string copy like snprintf, which will always null terminate and won't go off your array.

Always check return codes.